# Storing variable inside a string in the database, and translating at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I am trying to make a module in my application to where a user(read admin) can store a templated email message in the database - which the application will send at a triggered event.

I have tried string.Format(message,modelVar), however it fails since it does not see it as valid.

I present the user with a "friendly name" for the model variable, and store it as [modelVar.field] in the database. I do this so the user doesn't really get to see the actual database table name or model name associated with the field.  I translated that at runtime to {modelVar.field}, but that doesn't seem to work either.

The user will see the message in the application as "message message message [modelVar.field]..."

Does anyone know how i can store the variable.fieldName in the database in a safe way that I can actually translate into runtime code, and how would i go about doing that?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way, but i was hoping for a more elegant solution.

```
private string processCode(string bodyText, tbl_user user)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (bodyText.Count(a => a == '[') > 0 || counter > 100)
        {
            int first = bodyText.IndexOf("[") + 1;
            int next = bodyText.IndexOf("]", first) + 1;
            int length = (bodyText.Length - first) + (bodyText.Length - next);
            string variable = bodyText.Substring(first, length - 1);
            string field = variable.Replace($"{nameof(user)}.", "");
            string value = user.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(user).ToString();
            bodyText=bodyText.Replace($"[{variable}]", value);
            counter++;
        }
        return bodyText;
    }
```

**Edit:**
used a more simple loop as suggested by Glen

```
private static string processCode(string bodyText, tbl_user tco)
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = tco.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        string value = prop.GetValue(tco).ToString();
        bodyText = bodyText.Replace($"[tco.{prop.Name }]", value);
    }
    return bodyText;
}
```

Comment: Could you not do it the other way round and iterate through the properties of user:
foreach (var p in user.GetType().GetProperties())
{
        bodytext.Replace($"[{p.Name}]",          user.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(user).ToString());   
}. That way you only have to loop through once per property of user rather than once per line of the template

Comment: I can.  i'll update above to show the different loop.